# "Gather up your possibles"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

There is a line in the movie *The Alamo* by John Wayne's character Colonel Crockett talking to his men:

> Davy Crockett: First, the young lady and I will take a pasear. Gather up your **possibles** and I'll meet up with you later.

He then leaves with the young lady, before sending her off and coming back to join his band to march to the Alamo. **Possible** as noun appears to mean "possibiliy", according to Oxford Online Dictionaries. But what does it mean here? Judging from the context, my hunch is that Crockett here is telling others to gather their *things/belongings*, but I can't find this meaning under **possible**.

Comment: More context might help, since you didn't say who he is speaking to, and what is going on with that character. But if were to paraphrase it: "Gather up the things/situations that you believe are possible and I'll meet up with you later."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word in this context is discussed at length on [this radio show](https://www.waywordradio.org/your-possibles/). The show is researched and presented by author/journalist Martha Barnette and lexicographer/linguist Grant Barrett.

It is explained that the term means "one's personal belongings" - specifically the things that you might take with you on a trip.

Evidently, the term was coined because it refers to things that you might "possibly need" on a trip, so it refers to essentials for the journey rather than all the possessions you have. Today, we might use the term "essentials" instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a *good* reference for this - just [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/possibles), which doesn't have a source for it - but it makes sense, fits context and is otherwise attested. *Possibles*, as an always-plural noun, is apparently American frontier jargon - from the era when there was much of a frontier - and means the essential personal equipment of a frontiersman.

Thus, in this case, he's saying "gather up your stuff".

Answer (score -1):

I found this [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/possible) definition might fit your context:

> 8. singular noun
>
> The possible is everything that can be done in a situation.  *He is a
>   democrat with the skill, nerve, and ingenuity to push the limits of
>   the possible.*